# servlet package access and netbean default inclusion

Tags: java, jsp

I am wondering how NetBeans handles my package that contains my class source code to be compiled as a servlet

For manual cases in which I only install Tomcat or any other webservers and have them work out with my servlet, I may need to access my jsp page as `http://host/app/mypackage.myclassname/`

But in case of netbeans, things become easier as it do all stuff underneath for me and I only need to call something  like
`http://host/app/myclassname/`

and it works. There is no need to use a dot to call my class from a specified package name. Awesome!

By the way, how is doGet, doPost functions are processed. They don't seem to be called anywhere in my code but they are called when I specify their class container name in my URL.

Thank you so much for any replies.

Comment: Sorry, but its not clear from your question as to what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

> By the way, how is doGet, doPost functions are processed. They don't seem to be called anywhere in my code but they are called when I specify their class container name in my URL.

You can configure the `Servlet` to listen on a *particular* (*certain*) `HTTP URL Pattern` that can configure via `web.xml` or with `annotation` (JavaEE 6 spec).

When a servlet is requested, its *doGet()* or *doPost()* method will be called based upon the request method (GET or POST).

For instance, for POST request  :

```
<form method="post" action="your_servlet_url">
  ...
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

FAQ - [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)